# How do I download a picture using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, http

I want to download this picture using Ruby. How do I do that?

```
http://farm1.static.flickr.com/92/218926700_ecedc5fef7_o.jpg
```

I am using Mac OS.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
require "open-uri"

open("your-url") {|f|
   File.open("whatever_file.jpg","wb") do |file|
     file.puts f.read
   end
}
```

Comment: yeah, I forgot to add it in the first version.

Comment: tangentially, if you're on Windows (unlike the OP), you'll need to open the file in binary mode:  File.open(filename, 'w').binmode do |file| ...

Comment: I think this can be written more succinctly: `File.write('whatever_file.jpg', open('your-url').read, {mode: 'wb'})`.

Comment: This is not memory efficient, because it reads the whole image contents into memory. The best way (that not many people know about) is `IO.copy_stream(f, file)`. This will copy contents from one IO to another IO in the most efficient way possible.

Answer (score 18):

Try using the Mechanize gem:

Start with: `gem install mechanize` to install Mechanize.

Then:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
link = 'http://www.asite.com/pic.jpg'
agent.get(link).save "images/pic.jpg"
```

EDIT:
To make things cleaner I would suggest you use the File's name itself when you save the image. I had an issue saving bulk images because they were not formated correctly. The images were saved like this:

```
#pic.jpg(1)
#pic.jpg(2)
#etc.
```

Thats why you should probably use the image name as the file name like this:

```
agent.get(src).save "images/#{File.basename(url)}"
```

File.basename takes the image url and just returns the the actual image name:

```
File.basename("http://www.asite.com/pic.jpg")
# returns the image name
pic.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to download all the images on one page, you can use the image_downloader gem:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'image_downloader'

downloader = ImageDownloader::Process.new('www.test.com','img_dir/')

downloader.parse(:any_looks_like_image => true)

downloader.download()
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a gem called `down` which is simple to use.

Firstly, install this gem by `gem install down`.

Then:

```
require "down"
file = Down.download("http://farm1.static.flickr.com/92/218926700_ecedc5fef7_o.jpg")
```

You can read more on this gem in its github repo https://github.com/janko-m/down.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to require `open-uri` and use that with the previous answer or use the also supplied Net::HTTP module with its get method.

Answer (score 0):

To make things cleaner I would suggest you use the File's name itself when you save the image. I had an issue saving bulk images because they were not formated correctly. The images were saved like this:

```
#pic.jpg(1)
#pic.jpg(2)
#etc.
```

Thats why you should probably use the image name as the file name like this:

```
src = 'http://www.asite.com/pic.jpg'    
agent.get(src).save "#{folder}/#{File.basename(src)}"
```

File.basename takes the image url and just returns the the actual image name:

```
File.basename("http://www.asite.com/pic.jpg")
# returns the image name
pic.jpg
```

Answer (score -2):

```
%x(wget http://farm1.static.flickr.com/92/218926700_ecedc5fef7_o.jpg)
```

or

```
`wget http://farm1.static.flickr.com/92/218926700_ecedc5fef7_o.jpg`
```

Comment: This doesn’t work on macOS. Not unless you specifically install `wget`. Had you suggested `curl` (which comes by default), it would have been more acceptable.

Comment: He also asked for something in Ruby, using a shell doesn't count.

Answer (score -5):

The same way you download anything else. [Net::HTTP](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTP.html)