# Images don't download correctly Ruby

Tags: ruby, open-uri

I'm trying to make a simple program that downloads a file (image) from the Internet and stores it on my computer using Ruby. I get it to download something but the images look really weird. I run Windows 10 and Ruby 2.2.3. This is my code:

```
require "open-uri"
require "openSSL"
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

File.open("test.jpg", "w+") do |f|
    open("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c9/Moon.jpg","r") do |file|
        f.puts file.read
    end
end
```

These two lines:

```
require "openSSL"
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

are to solve a problem where I get this error if I try to download a file via https:

```
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

Better solutions for this are very welcome!

Here is one example when I tried to download this image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c9/Moon.jpg the downloaded file looked like this: [test.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQJrr.jpg)

But it only seems to happen to images. HTML files look exactly the same. I know images can look different depending on file type but the URL ends with .jpg and when you download it via for example chrome, it is stored as a .jpg.

All suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Don't you want to use the write-binary flag?  For example: `open("file_to_write", "wb")`.

Comment: @orde It was that simple! Thank you! :3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I download a picture using ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074309/how-do-i-download-a-picture-using-ruby)