# Check time between 2pm and 8am

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How to check if time is between 2pm and 8am ? This is not working:

```
value = Time.current.between?(Time.parse("2:00pm"), Time.parse("8:00am")) ? 9 : 4
```

If time is 1AM it should return 9, else 4(I want 9 if evening or night. If 'normal during day' - 4)
Any idea?

Comment: swap 2:00pm and 8:00am.  first argument should be the lower value and 8:00am comes first before 2:00pm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I download a picture using ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074309/how-do-i-download-a-picture-using-ruby)

Comment: @boulder_ruby Did you paste the wrong link by mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

swap 2:00pm and 8:00am. first argument should be the lower value and 8:00am comes first before 2:00pm.

```
[3] pry(main)> Time.current
=> 2016-01-13 09:21:14 +0800
[4] pry(main)> Time.current.between?(Time.parse('9:00am'), Time.parse('2:00pm'))
=> true
[5] pry(main)> Time.parse('1:00am').between?(Time.parse('9:00am'), Time.parse('2:00pm'))
=> false
```

UPDATE

You can also use `Time.current.hour.between?(9, 16)`

Comment: But it not working(or i do something wrong). I want 9 if evening or night. If 'normal during day' - 4