# In Ruby how can I tell what the extension is to an image file that's hosted on the internet?

Tags: ruby, open-uri

I want to download some images from the web, however some of the URLs do not specify the file extension such as:

```
http://sportslabs-webproxy.imgix.net/http%3A%2F%2Fkty-platform-prod.silverchalice.co%2Fv3%2Fimages%2Fcontents%2F55bbe945e4b073340d3851fb?fit=clip&h=532&w=800&s=61b00197aca130a83de011484841158e
```

I was going to use the following method mentioned in "[How do I download a picture using Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074309/how-do-i-download-a-picture-using-ruby/1074324#1074324)" to download the files, but as I said wasn't sure how to tell the script what file extension to save it as.

Comment: You can't count on file extensions or anything the server tells you about the file. The file could have been on the server without an extension or it could have been saved as a blob without a file-type/extension. Download the file, save it as binary and sniff out what type it is, not trusting anything the remote side said about it. Once you've determined the file type then rename the file to use the appropriate extension. Imagine the fun you'd have trusting a server that's been hacked and is serving malicious content that you then blindly trust.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into the [ruby-filemagic](https://github.com/blackwinter/ruby-filemagic) gem.

For example:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'filemagic'

url = 'http://sportslabs-webproxy.imgix.net/http%3A%2F%2Fkty-platform-prod.silverchalice.co%2Fv3%2Fimages%2Fcontents%2F55bbe945e4b073340d3851fb?fit=clip&h=532&w=800&s=61b00197aca130a83de011484841158e'

open('raw_file', 'wb') do |file|
  file << open(url).read
end

puts FileMagic.new(FileMagic::MAGIC_MIME).file( 'raw_file' )
# => 'image/jpeg; charset=binary'
```

UPDATE: To find the extension to save the file as you can use [mime-types](https://github.com/halostatue/mime-types)

```
content_type = FileMagic.new(FileMagic::MAGIC_MIME).file( 'raw_file' ).split( ';' ).first

require 'mime/types'
puts MIME::Types[content_type].first.extensions.first 
# => 'jpeg'
```

Comment: This is definitely the safest path to follow.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Content-Type` HTTP header. For the URL you provided, the headers are:

```
$ curl -I "http://sportslabs-webproxy.imgix.net/http%3A%2F%2Fkty-platform-prod.silverchalice.co%2Fv3%2Fimages%2Fcontents%2F55bbe945e4b073340d3851fb?fit=clip&h=532&w=800&s=61b00197aca130a83de011484841158e"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public,no-transform,max-age=86400,s-maxage=86400
Last-Modified: Mon, 01 Feb 2016 20:08:08 GMT
Content-Length: 35176
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: image/jpeg
...
```

Here, you can see that the image is a JPEG. You can use a MIME-type library, e.g. [mime-types for Ruby](https://github.com/mime-types/ruby-mime-types/) to determine which extension to use given the content type.

The vast majority of servers will specify a `Content-Type` header. If it's not specified, you can use Eric's approach to infer the file type from the contents.

If you want to stick with `open-uri`, you can use the [`content_type`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI/Meta.html) field to get the `Content-Type`:

```
require 'open-uri'

url = 'http://sportslabs-webproxy.imgix.net/http%3A%2F%2Fkty-platform-prod.silverchalice.co%2Fv3%2Fimages%2Fcontents%2F55bbe945e4b073340d3851fb?fit=clip&h=532&w=800&s=61b00197aca130a83de011484841158e'
open(url) { |file|
  content_type = file.content_type
  # Determine extension, copy file to disk, ...
}
```

Comment: That assumes the server knows what the content-type is. Dynamically served "rich objects" often are sent as binary with nothing specific for the file type and it's up to the browser or receiving software to figure it out. And, the programmer for the system could set the value to the wrong file-type. It's better to sniff the type after the file has been downloaded rather than rely on anything the server says.

Comment: Note that `open-uri` IO objects have a `content_type` method that you can query directly; no need to go through `meta`.

Comment: @theTinMan agreed, I do like that approach better. I have actually used ImageMagick libraries to infer image types before after hitting those exact issues with `Content-Type`, but that slipped my mind. I'll leave this answer as another tool in the chest, but I also prefer Eric's approach.

Answer (score 1):

A lightweight option is the [fastimage gem](https://github.com/sdsykes/fastimage). Here's example usage:

```
require 'fastimage'
FastImage.type("http://stephensykes.com/images/pngimage")
=> :png
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have a couple options. The first thing you can do is trust the web server to correctly identify the type in the `Content-Type:` header.  Here's an example (requires the `mime-types` Rubygem):

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'mime/types'

url = 'http://sportslabs-webproxy.imgix.net/http%3A%2F%2Fkty-platform-prod.silverchalice.co%2Fv3%2Fimages%2Fcontents%2F55bbe945e4b073340d3851fb?fit=clip&h=532&w=800&s=61b00197aca130a83de011484841158e' 
open(url) do |f|
  filename = File.basename url
  if filename !~ /\./ then
    t = MIME::Type[f.content_type]
    if t && t.first && t.first.extensions then
       filename += ".#{t.first.extensions.first}"
    end
  end
  open(filename, 'w') do |w|
   w.write(f.read)
  end
end
```

But you might be better off using Eric's solution and inspecting the file after you download it to make sure it's really what you think it is.

Comment: Don't trust a server. They can be misinformed, and they can lie. In either case blindly trusting them results in a fragile system. It's always better to sniff the file to determine whether it's actually what it's supposed to be.

Comment: @theTinMan It really depends on if you control the server or not.  If you do, you can trust the `Content-Type` and not waste the extra processing power it takes to sniff the file itself.  If you don't control the server, then yes I totally agree with you.

Comment: Even if you own the server you have to be careful if you aren't responsible for the content stored on it. Servers where people can upload content can have untrustworthy files, files that are misnamed or are missing the extension. If you own 100% of the system/server/content then it's pretty safe but if a user can touch that content then look out.